# Handling Context In Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns, properties-file

I'm working on a small project and I'm looking for a good way to handle context in spring. I find myself creating a context holder class to hold my properties using setter injection. The problem I'm having with this is that I'm grabbing a context object and passing it around. I'm looking for a design pattern or something that can help me do this in a cleaner way. As a simple example let's say I'm currently doing something like the below, where the fields are injected through setter injection and I'm looking for a better way to inject the properties Also, pretend I had a large amount of properties, too large to use something like @Value cleanly:

```
public class MyContext{

    private String configItem1;
    private String configItem2;
    private String configItem3;


    public void setConfigItem1(String configItem1){
        this.configItem1 = configItem1;
    }

    public void setConfigItem2(String configItem2){
        this.configItem2 = configItem1;
    }

    public void setConfigItem3(String configItem3){
        this.configItem3 = configItem1;
    }

}
```

Sample spring context:

```
<bean id="appProperties"
       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:my-app.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


<bean id="myContext" class="these.are.not.the.droids.you.are.looking.for.context.MyContext" >
     <property name="configItem1" value="${some.item.1}" />
     <property name="configItem2" value ="${some.item.2}"/>
     <property name="configItem3" value="${some.item.3}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered simply using a Map to store the values? Java is inherently a verbose language. So I guess you don't have much choice otherwise.
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/FillMap.htm

Answer (score 0):

**If your config values are specific to a request**, then you can use a ThreadLocal ([API for ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)) which can hold values across the layers in an "invocation context". You can populate this ThreadLocal varaible in your controller and use it any layer in the same invocation chain.

**If your settings are applicable across requests** then you can use ApplicationContext to store the values. You can access ApplicationContext like this in Spring -

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```